# Transformation and aggregation of MB to TB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset in SQL Server, where I would like to convert multiple columns from MB to TB as well as subtract the two columns with the condition set to a specific date.

```
totalMB     freeMB  date
12204984    6493286 11/2/2020
```

Desired output

```
totalTB freeTB  usedTB   date
11.63   6.19    5.44    11/2/2020
```

This is what I am doing:

```
SELECT totalMB, freeMB, date, (totalMB/(1024*1024) AS totalTB, (freeMB/(1024*1024) AS freeTB), 
totalTB - freeTB AS usedTB
FROM table
where date = '2020/11/2'
```

However, I am not getting an error - invalid syntax and not the desired output. I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Can you share the exact error you're getting please?

Comment: `(totalMB/(1024*1024)` is missing `)`, the last `)` on line 1 is in the wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot repeat column aliases in the `select`.  But you can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT t.totalMB, t.freeMB, t.date, v.totalTB, v.freeTB, 
       (v.totalTB - v.freeTB) AS usedTB
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (t.totalMB/(1024*1024), t.freeMB/(1024*1024))
     ) v(TotalTB, freeTB)
WHERE date = '2020-11-02'
```

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, if I wish to now sum that newly created v.totalTB column, could I just add -- sum(v.totalTB) within this query?

Comment: ok I figured it out : SUM(MyColumn) OVER () AS ..